# Can I deploy mysql in the openshift and access from the outter

Tags: mysql, openshift

I create a diy Appliation and add a mysql cartridge and bind it to the port 8080.Is it possible to access outside the network through domain? I have a little idea about the routing
system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what you want here. But you can use `putty` in your local machine to connect to Openshift mysql.

Thank you

Comment: I want access the mysql from the other cartridge?Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use port forwarding using the 'rhc' command line or using the OpenShift Tooling in JBoss Tools. In both case, you'll have a set of local sockets to connect to, and it will forward commands to the remote 3306 port on your OpenShift gear, so you can run MySQL/SQL commands on your database.